# shifting Label in array of JLabel in swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to shift my elements in my array of JLabel
labels values depends on TextField values for example if I entered 10 my labels show 10 , if I entered 10 then 12 my labels shows 10 12 that works perfectly 
I want to make it sorted for example if I entered 10 then 6 labels show 6 then 10 that not works

```
 int j;

 for(j=0;j<Items;j++) {
     if(Integer.parseInt(labels[j].getText())
         > Integer.parseInt(uatxt[1].getText())) 
     break;

     for(int k=Items;k>j;k--){
         labels[k]=labels[k-1];
         labels[j]= new JLabel(uatxt[1].getText());
         labels[j].setBounds(40*j, 150, 130, 30);
         p.add(labels[j]);
         p.revalidate();
         p.repaint();
         Items++;

        //labels is my array
        //Items is number of elements in array
        // p is panel
        //uatxt[1] is my TextField 

    }
}
```

sorry if my question is trivial but i`m beginner in swing

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by your question. Do you want to change the label text of JLabel from a TextField? You should also restructure your code so it is easier to read by using proper indentations.

Comment: I think now is more clearly ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do anything in the graphics, this problem is a logical problem.

After reading the field, tokenize them into an array:

```
String text = field.getText();
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(text);
while(scan.hasNextInt())
    nums.add(scan.nextInt());

Collections.sort(nums)
```

Here you have beautifully sorted numbers in an `ArrayList`.